# Downloading android SDK on Ubuntu PC

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I did run the below command according to the SDK Readme.txt placed inside the SDK:

```
$tools/android update sdk --no-ui
```

but I get the below errors :

Refresh Sources:

```
Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Unknown Host dl.google.com
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl.google.com
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl.google.com
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl.google.com
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl.google.com
```

If I try to do the same using Android-Studio->SDK Manager I get the same error in the message Box.

Is this due to the no proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like a proxy or other networking issue. Try pinging that address with `ping dl.google.com` . You should get back something like:

```
PING dl.l.google.com (216.58.219.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mia07s25-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.219.110): icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=35.2 ms
64 bytes from mia07s25-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.219.110): icmp_req=2 ttl=47 time=29.2 ms
```

until you cancel the command with Control-C.

Comment: I get : ping: unknown host dl.google.com and strangely : dl.google.com in the browser leads me to http://www.google.com/chrome/ :) !

Comment: You definitely shouldn't get an unknown host error for dl.google.com, but the behavior in the browser is expected. Google apparently assumes that you attempted to browse that page inadvertently and remaps it.  If you're getting to any Google site, then your network is at least partially working.

Comment: Is your pinging result you posted from behind the proxy or with no proxy?